# Filling a structure

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make a C program in which user is able to add multiple students to the list. The point of that is to **create a database** of students (**without accessing a .txt file**, It just has to be able to add students and then search for a specific student by surname in the same run, no saving).

```
struct student{
int semester;
char major[20];
char name[20];
};

struct person{
int id;
char surname[30];
struct student data;
}stud;

typedef struct person* st[10];
int m=0;

int add(){
printf("Type student's surname\n");
st[m]->surname=getchar(); //that's basically the part in which I need help
m=m+1;
}
```

While I think I can handle searching, I don't really know how to do the adding part. I want to keep it as simple as possible (I'm a freshman). My intent is to use structure **person** (with **student** nested to it) and then whenever the user calls function **add** they'll be able to add one student (let's say that the max is 10). My idea was to make 10 structures (struct[m]) with m rising each time function **add** is called, but it seems not to work the way I expected.

How can I make it happen? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try to break your task into smaller problems. Separate input from creating entries. Use constants in test routines to test your ideas. So make a function which just adds  a student like strcpy(aStructInstance.surname, "test name"). Then work up to using the array.  You will quickly see where your problems are.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)  If you really intended to define an array of pointers to a structure type, it might be reasonable to define the type, but that probably wasn't what you had in mind.  Did you intend to define the unused variable `stud`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
typedef struct person* st[10];
```

Here you are not creating an array, you are defining a type named `st` which can be used to later declare a size 10 array of pointers to `struct person`

```c
st[m]->surname=getchar();
```

Hence this part should not compile as `st` is a type. Also, if you want to make an array of pointers as you are doing there, you also have to allocate those structures on the heap using `malloc` ([more info here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)).

I suggest you to instead allocate the structures on the stack, you can do it changing the `typedef` line to this:

```c
struct person st[10];
```